# Iterating through references to variables in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, pointers

I am looking for a way to change the values of multiple variables using iteration in Swift. An example would be something like this:

```
var a = false
var b = false
var c = false

func makeAllTrue() {
    for n in [a, b, c] {
        n = true
    }
}
```

...but rather than an array of values, I want to iterate through an array of pointers/references to the variables above.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You might be able to do this with key paths... Is this in a class or a struct? Anyway, this sounds like an XY problem. Why are you doing this in the first place? If `a`, `b` and `c` are _so_ related, can't you just replace `a`, `b` and `c` with a single array property instead?

Comment: That is, replace the declarations of `a`, `b`, `c` with `var foo = [false, false, false]`, and change the loop to `for i in foo.indices { foo[i] = true }`.

Comment: @Sweeper  Thanks for the suggestion. The reason I wanted to do this in a manner above is that I have a huge list of variables that I will mostly call individually. However, I also want to be able to change all at once (such as when restoring default values, etc) without having to type out each individually or resorting to a dictionary and key values.

Comment: What's wrong with a dictionary? And even with a dictionary, or an array, you still have to type out each individually!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```swift
var a = false
var b = false
var c = false

mutateValues(&a, &b, &c) { n in
    n = true
}

print(a, b, c) // will be printed "true true true"

func mutateValues<Value>(_ values: UnsafeMutablePointer<Value>..., mutate: (inout Value) -> Void) {
    values.forEach {
        mutate(&$0.pointee)
    }
}
```

Comment: I knew there is a dirty trick like this! Wouldn't recommend this though, given the OP's situation.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to do this with key paths. Let's say the properties are in a class `Foo`:

```
class Foo {
    var a = false
    var b = false
    var c = false
    
    func makeAllTrue() {
        for n in [\Foo.a, \Foo.b, \Foo.c] {
            self[keyPath: n] = true
        }
    }
}
```

If `Foo` is a struct, use  `mutating func` instead:

```
struct Foo {
    var a = false
    var b = false
    var c = false
    
    mutating func makeAllTrue() {
        for n in [\Foo.a, \Foo.b, \Foo.c] {
            self[keyPath: n] = true
        }
    }
}
```

However, if the class name is long, I don't think it is worth doing this way.

If these three properties are *very* related, I would not bother with the key path stuff and replace `a`, `b` and `c` with an array:

```
var abc = [false, false, false]
```

and have the for loop loop over the indices:

```
for i in abc.indices {
    abc[i] = true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An Array in Swift is a struct, hence a value type.

Iterating over his children, and changing one, will not be possible unless:

- The type of child is aa class (which is reference typed)
- You iterate over the indices and change the real values!

  - E.G:

    ```
    var a: Int = 1
    var b: Int = 2
    var array: [Int] = [a,b]

    for index in array.indices {
       array[index] += 1
    }

    print(array)      // [2,3]
    ```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I had a hunch that this was the case...

Comment: Cool! You can upvote my answer if it helped :)
Have a good one!